# Unable to link stylesheet and images in wordpress using my own themes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've uploaded my own design.I just can't get the stylesheet linked correctly. currently my theme resides insides wp-content-themes-(carrental->my theme folder name)-style.css.
My index.php page is also in the same folder as style.css.

I'm linking like this:

```
// for the style.css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('style.css'); ?>" type="text/css"  />

// for image in index.php
<img src="<?php bloginfo('carrental'); ?>/assets/acr-logo-1.jpg" width="200" height="100">
```

What is the correct way of linking please?

Comment: Please see comment added under my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will return the stylesheet path

```
bloginfo('stylesheet_url');
```

so use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
```

to echo out the stylesheet link!

More information regarding **bloginfo** can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

Comment: I did used like you suggested, but no effect.<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('style.css'); ?>">

Comment: What you posted above is not what I suggested. Copy the full code listed in the second code block of my answer and paste it into your php file. It will work. The function returns the path, you don't pass the 'style.css' as a parameter to the function, you pass 'stylesheet_url' to get a returned value of your stylesheet path.

Comment: For images, just use <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?> before your image paths :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to include your stylesheet and script files is via [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) inside your functions.php. Take for reference the default activated theme on wordpress (twentyfourteen for example).

Using wp_enqueue_script for example, will ensure that a script file is loaded once, no matter what, so no unpleasant surprises on the way. Take jquery for example, you can add it as a dependency for other scripts.

If you prefer to include in your index.php's header, you can use more options:
- ">, another option is to use ...src="echo get_stylesheet_uri()".. or you can use other functions that return your theme path, like others have already written here.

The idea is to output the function return, so get_stylesheet_uri() won't work, because you don't echo it. You use get_stylesheet_uri() when you want to store the value inside a variable.

But the prefered way is still using wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style functions.

Answer (score 0):

for style sheet you must use link elemnt of styles

```
bloginfo('stylesheet_url');
```

for images you must give the full url of the image 
like if your images directory inside your theme then in an image source you can give this

```
bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/imagname.png'
```

Comment: Shah Rukh....can u tell me how exactly to display images..my images stored inside..assets foldes.And I display like this,<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory/assets/acr-logo-1.jpg'); ?>" width="200" height="100">

Comment: where `assets` folder location ? is it in `public_html` or else where ?

Comment: localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/(carrental)/assets

Comment: I think then you must use this `<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/assets/acr-logo-1.jpg'); ?>" width="200" height="100">`

Comment: Thanks alot..I tried this way and it worked..<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/acr-logo-1.jpg" width="200" height="100">

Answer (score 0):

Dont use absolute url.. Use full url. See below code

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css" />
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/acr-logo-1.jpg' ?>" />
```

Comment: `<style>` tag contain `src` how ?

Comment: Sory it was written by mistake... But my main point is not to use absolute url.. Hope u get it